# Why I get typescript error: Argument of type 'string | FilterData[] | number[] | Moment[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I need to use different types in my code for different cases. The type could be string, number[], FilterData[] (my custom type) or Moment[] type depending on the situation. I set the type as

```
export type ExpandedFiltered = {
  [key: string]: string | number[] | Moment[] | FilterData[]
}
```

I am getting this error,

> Argument of type 'string | FilterData[] | number[] | Moment[]' is not
> assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Why is string not assignable to type when string is??? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

it's not that string is not assignable to string, the problem is the rest of it. to be more clear "FilterData[] | number[] | Moment[]" is not assignable to string. since the first type can be something other than string, you can not assign it to a string.
PS: however it seems you have missed the part of code that causes error.
let's say it like this:

```
a : string;
b : ExpandedFiltered;
```

then this is valid.

```
b = a;
```

on the other hand, this is invalid:

```
a = b;
```

because you can't be sure b is string, though you can't assign b to a.